# Algebraic Exponent GCSE Edexcel Exam Question. Help Please...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

x = $2^p$
, y = $2^q$

(a) Express in terms of x and/or y,

(i) $2^{p + q}$

(ii) $2^{2q}$

(iii) $2^{p -1}$

My Working Out:

(i) x + $√y$ 
because $2^p$ is equal to x and I think $√2^q$ is equal to q

However, I have no idea how to do (ii) or (iii)

I thought maybe (ii) could be $y^2$ but wouldn't that be $(2^q)^2$ which is $4^q$ $^2$.

Thank You and Help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Consider $q= \log_2 2^q$.

Comment: I haven't learnt about log yet in school.

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question.  Did you mean $2^{p - 1}$?  The use of logarithms is required for the first two parts of the question.

Comment: It's not in my syllabus to learn about Logarithms at this current moment in time so is there another way to answer this question?

Comment: @xx_Gcsemathstudent_xx Do you mean to simplify $2^{p+q}$, $2^{2q}$, and $2^{p-1}$? I'm also doing IGCSE and these questions only use basic properties of exponents, not logarithms.

Comment: Oh sorry yes I meant that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mistyped.

For $(i)$, assuming you meant $2^{p+q}$, the answer is $xy$, since $a^b\times a^c=a
^{b+c}$

For $(ii)$, assuming you meant $2^{2q}$, the answer is $y^2$ just as you thought, since $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$.

For $(iii)$, (which I think you typed correctly), the answer is $\frac {x}2$ since $\frac 12=2^{-1}$ and $2^{-1}\times 2^p=2^{p-1}$.

Comment: Thank You So Much for helping me.